# Laravel 5.2 + mono log critical error send to mail

Tags: email, mono, laravel-5

How I can send every critical error exception to email. in current Laravel 5.2 it log in `/storage/logs/laravel.log` file. I want get that critical error in to mail with MailHandler but don't know how to implement it.

in file we get this type of error :

```
[2017-12-07 09:32:51] local.ERROR: ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in /home/ilogix/Workspace/cudefender/site/app/Http/Controllers/FormsController.php:53
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ilogix/Workspace/cudefender/site/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(301): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/home/ilogix/Wo...')
#1 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('App\\Http\\Contro...')
#2 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('App\\Http\\Contro...')
#3 /home/ilogix/Workspace/cudefender/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(280): ReflectionMethod->__construct('App\\Http\\Contro...', 'index')
```

i need same in email by monolog mail handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file to send emails to a given address. For example, edit the `report` function to:

```
public function report(Exception $e)
{

    try {
      \Mail::raw( $e->__toString(), function ( $m ) {
        $m->from('no-reply@your-app.com', 'APP_NAME');
        $m->to( 'name@domain.com' )->subject('APP_NAME - Fatal Error' );
      });
    } catch ( \Exception $e ) {
      // ignore
    }

    parent::report($e);
}
```

This code will send the contents of the Exception `$e` to `name@domain.com`. You can change the from address, and subject to be anything you want.

Depending on the error encountered, the message you receive would look like:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException in
>   your-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php:161
>
> Stack trace: #0
>   your-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(821):
>   Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->match(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
>
> ...